# Android Java: string returns empty while it's not?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm trying to grab the HTML code of a webpage with `HttpClient()` in Android. `getbodyHtml` returns empty, while in the output I see the HTML code printed fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
class GetResult implements Runnable {
    public volatile String bodyHtml;
    public volatile boolean finished = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        finished = false;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            String myUri = "http://google.com";

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUri);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

            bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            //return bodyHtml;

            finished = true;
            System.out.println(bodyHtml);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    public String getbodyHtml(){
        return bodyHtml;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
String rs = "";
GetResult foo = new GetResult();
new Thread(foo).start();
if (foo.finished = true){
   rs = foo.getbodyHtml();
}

edittext2.setText(rs);
```

Comment: `if (foo.finished = true){` but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Foo is not finished when you do the check, and do not enter in to the if. To correct this call foo.join(), like this:

```
                String rs = "";
                GetResult foo = new GetResult();
                new Thread(foo).start();
                foo.join(); // will wait till foo finish

                rs = foo.getbodyHtml();


            edittext2.setText(rs);
```

Comment: @murdoch If you just call finish right after calling start, then there was no point in making this a thread.  Also you should not call finish on the main UI thread, because that will make you're UI non responsive.  You should use an AsyncTask for this.